# Cant get the Edit function Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have two models `Employee` and `Overtime Definition` The Associations are set like this

Employee

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :overtime_definitions
```

Overtime Definition

```
class OvertimeDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :employee
```

I created an Overtime definition for an employee and it all looks fine.However I'm having trouble with editing the same for an employee.

**overtime_definitions__controller:**

```
    def new
        @flag = params[:flag]
        @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
        @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.new
     end

      def create
        @employee = Employee.find(params[:overtime_definition][:employee_id])
        @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.new(params[:overtime_definition])
        if (params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s !="" || params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s !="")
          @overtime.half_day_extra_duty_hours   = params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s + ":" + params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s + ":" + "00"
        else
         @overtime.half_day_extra_duty_hours = nil
        end
        if (params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s !="" || params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s !="")
          @overtime.full_day_extra_duty_hours   = params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s + ":" + params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s + ":" + "00"
        else
         @overtime.full_day_extra_duty_hours = nil
        end
     if @overtime.save
      flash[:notice] = "Overtime Successfully Created for #{@employee.name}"
      redirect_to :action => 'search_overtime'
    end
  end

def edit
    @flag = params[:flag]
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id][:employee_id])
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id])
    if @overtime.update_attributes(params[:overtime_definition])
     flash[:notice] = "Overtime Successfully Updated for #{@employee.name}"
            redirect_to :action => 'search_overtime'
    else
     render :action => 'edit',:flag=>params[:flag]
    end
  end
```

Tried with these in the edit method

1. `@overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id][:employee_id])`

   #gives me `can't convert Symbol into Integer` error.
2. `@overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id])`

   #gives me `Couldn't find OvertimeDefinition with ID=1353` error.Actually 1353 is the id of that employee.

   3.`@overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:employee_id])`

   #gives me `couldn't find OvertimeDefinition without an ID` error.

My _search_overtime_employee_list having these links for new and edit actions

```
<%=link_to "Calculation" ,:action => "new",:id=>employee.id, :flag=>"Calculation" %>

<%= link_to "Re-Calculate",:action => "edit",:id=>employee.id,:flag=>"Re-Calculate" %>
```

**new.rhtml**

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' do %>
<%= render :partial =>'form'%>
<center>
    <%= submit_tag "Save",:onclick=>"return validate()",:class=>"buttons"%>
</center>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Back" ,:action => "search_overtime" %>
```

**edit.rhtml**

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'update', :id=>@employee.id,:flag=> params[:flag],:value=>params[:id] %>
<%= render :partial =>'form'%>
<center>
    <%= submit_tag "Update",:onclick=>"return validate()",:class=>"buttons"%>
</center>
<%= link_to "Back" ,:action => "search_overtime" %>
```

**_form.rhtml**

Employee Details

```
<table cellspacing="5">
 <tr>
    <td><b>Employee Code</b></td>
    <%= hidden_field 'overtime_definition','employee_id',:value=>params[:id] %>
    <td><%= @employee.employeeid %></td>
    <td><b>Employee Name</b></td>
    <td><%= @employee.personnel.display_full_name %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Department</b></td>
    <td><%=  @employee.department ? @employee.department.name : "" %></td>
    <td><b>Designation</b></td>
    <td><%= @employee.designation ? @employee.designation.name : "" %></td>
    <td><b>Location</b></td>
    <td><%= @employee.location.name%></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
</br>
<fieldset>
  <table cellspacing="5">

    <%= form_for :overtime_definition, :builder => LabelFormBuilder do |od| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <label for="half_day_extra_duty_hours">
       Half Day Extra Duty Hours
      </label>
      </td>
      <td class ="datefamily">
      <%= select_time(@overtime.half_day_extra_duty_hours, {:include_blank => true, :time_separator => ":",:prefix => "half_day_extra_duty_hours"})%>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <label for="full_day_extra_duty_hours">
       Full Day Extra Duty Hours
      </label>
      </td>
     <td class ="datefamily">
     <%= select_time(@overtime.full_day_extra_duty_hours, {:include_blank => true, :time_separator => ":",:prefix => "full_day_extra_duty_hours"})%>
      </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <%= od.sr_check_box :is_salary_basis, {}, true, false, :label => "Is Salary Basis"%>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <%= od.sr_check_box :is_fixed_amount, {}, true, false, :label => "Is Fixed Amount"%>
    <td colspan="2" id="ov_hm" style="display: none">
     Half Day Amount
    <%= od.text_field :half_day_amount, :onkeypress => "return numbersonly(event)", :style => "width:40px" %>
     </td>
     <td colspan="2" id="ov_fm" style="display: none">
     Full Day Amount
     <%= od.text_field :full_day_amount, :onkeypress => "return numbersonly(event)", :style => "width:40px" %>
     </td>
 </tr>
<%end%>

</table>
```

I just lost out here completely in getting that edit action work.Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look in your log file when you submit the form.  What parameters are coming through to your create action?  That's always a good place to start when trying to work out whether the problem is with your form code or controller code.  (if the params aren't what you expect then fix your form:  if the params are what you expect and they're not being processed correctly, fix your controller).

Comment: @MaxWilliams Very nice Hint! Thanks! I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `edit` link is:

```
<%= link_to "Re-Calculate",:action => "edit",:id=>employee.id,:flag=>"Re-Calculate" %>
```

In your edit action:

> @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id][:employee_id]) ## gives me can't convert Symbol into Integer error.

As per the edit link, you are directly passing `:id` in query params which you can access as `params[:id]`. There is no `params[:id][:employee_id]` in your params hash so when you say `params[:id][:employee_id]` Ruby tries to convert `:employee_id` to an integer which is a symbol. Hence, the error.

I think you should be passing id of OvertimeDefinition record in `:id` from your link. And access it as

```
@overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id])
```

in the Controller's action.

> @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id]) ## gives me Couldn't
>   find OvertimeDefinition with ID=1353 error.Actually 1353 is the id of
>   that employee.

This is because you are passing `employee id` in `params[:id]` so obviously this will not work. You need to pass OvertimeDefinition id here.

> @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:employee_id]) ## gives me
>   couldn't find OvertimeDefinition without an ID error.

You are not passing any `:employee_id` in query params within `edit` link. So, params[:employee_id] will be nil and `find` method fails because you didn't pass any id to it.

### Solution :

Update your `edit link` as below:

```
<%= link_to "Re-Calculate",:action => "edit",:id=> @overtimedefinition.id , :employee_id => employee.id,:flag=>"Re-Calculate" %>
```

Replace `@overtimedefinition.id` with appropriate id of OvertimeDefinition record. As you have not shared the code, I don't know the name of OvertimeDefinition variable.

Update your `edit` action as:

```
  def edit
    @flag = params[:flag]
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id])
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.But however now i have a problem with update action.It is not updating my data but converting `employee_id` to the `id` of `overtime`.It is weird.Cant figure out why.

Comment: I added it as a separate question to give more details.Please have a look at this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954601/update-action-seems-to-be-doing-nothing

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll check it out if its not already resolved. :)