# how to pass parameters in params using form_tag method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass a parameter `params[:tab] => "drive"` in car_path method using form_tag  but it doesnt gets available in car_path params. Here is what i am trying

```
<%= 
form_tag(
    car_path(@user.id), 
    {
        :method => :get, 
        params[:tab] => "drive", 
        :class => "form form-horizontal"
     }
) do 
%>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this:

```
<%= form_tag(car_path(@user.id, :tab => "drive"), {:method => :get, :class => "form form-horizontal"}) do %>
```

Pass it with the `car_path` as a **query parameter.**

**UPDATE**

Look at `action="/visitors/198454?tab=drive"`, `tab = drive` is passed in params. Access it as **params[:tab]** in your controller.

Comment: Really!! share the HTML source code of form generated with this.

Comment: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/visitors/198454?tab=drive" class="form form-horizontal" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div> this is my page source

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓", "no"=>"", "email"=>"", "name"=>"", "dob"=>"", "commit"=>"Search", "action"=>"show", "controller"=>"car", "id"=>"1984"}   and this is my params list it doesnt have :tab field

Comment: @ArvindMehra params you have written in last comment are for show action, you first submit your form then see the params, you would get them.

Comment: How come your `"action"=>"show"` in params hash? Shouldn't it be related to `"/visitors/198454?tab=drive"`?

Comment: the form is being submit in the car controller's show action form_tag(car_path(@user.id, :tab => "drive")

Comment: @ArvindMehra action :show is designed to take one params, default being :id, in routes you can rename it, but it would not be possible to pass multiple params to :show action.

Comment: @ArvindMehra :show is for GET method, remember it. You should not submit a form to this action.

Comment: @KirtiThorat See This Post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912544/cant-get-the-edit-function-working You might have interested.My friend need your help there.

Comment: @Pavan I have posted an answer to your friend's question. Let me know if it resolves his issue.

Answer (score 29):

A little different idea: isn't it better to use a [hidden field](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) inside the form?

```rb
<%= hidden_field_tag :tab , "drive" %>
```