# Update action seems to be doing nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, parameter-passing

Currently,I have a `overtime_definition_controller` with methods like this

```
class Edms::OvertimeDefinitionsController < ApplicationController

  require 'will_paginate/array'
  layout :compute_layout


  def new
    @flag = params[:flag]
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.new
  end

  def create
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:overtime_definition][:employee_id])
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.new(params[:overtime_definition])
    if (params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s !="" || params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s !="")
      @overtime.half_day_extra_duty_hours   = params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s + ":" + params[:half_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s + ":" + "00"
    else
      @overtime.half_day_extra_duty_hours = nil
    end
    if (params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s !="" || params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s !="")
      @overtime.full_day_extra_duty_hours   = params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:hour].to_s + ":" + params[:full_day_extra_duty_hours][:minute].to_s + ":" + "00"
    else
      @overtime.full_day_extra_duty_hours = nil
    end
    if @overtime.save
      flash[:notice] = "Overtime Successfully Created for #{@employee.name}"
      redirect_to :action => 'search_overtime'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @flag = params[:flag]
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id])
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
  end

  def update
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id])
    if @overtime.update_attributes(params[:overtime_definition])
      flash[:notice] = "Overtime Successfully Updated for #{@employee.name}"
      redirect_to :action => 'search_overtime'
    else
      render :action => 'edit',:flag=>params[:flag]
    end
  end

  def search_overtime
    @overtimes = OvertimeDefinition.all
    @departments = @site.is_central ? {} : @site.departments
    @designations = @site.is_central ? {} : @site.designations
    @active_profile = @site.is_central ? Employee.get_all_employees.paginate(:page => params[:page]) : @site.employees.get_all_employees.paginate(:page => params[:page]) 
    if request.xml_http_request?
      render :update do |page|
      page['search_result_div'].replace_html :partial => "search_overtime_employee_list"
    end
  end
end
```

However when i tried to update,it does nothing.

**The values before update:**

`id = 235`,`employee_id = 1353` and remaining fields.

**The values after update:**

`id = 235`,`employee_id = 235` and remaining values(same values as before update).

However,It is converting `employee_id` value to `id` of that `overtime_definition`. It is  weird.

**edit.rhtml**

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'update',:id => @overtime.id,:employee_id => @employee.id,:flag=> params[:flag] %>
<%= render :partial =>'form' %>
<center>
  <%= submit_tag "Update",:onclick=>"return validate()",:class=>"buttons" %>
</center>
<%= link_to "Back" ,:action => "search_overtime" %>
```

**_form.rhtml**

```
<table cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Employee Code</b></td>
    <%= hidden_field 'overtime_definition','employee_id',:value=>params[:id] %>
    <td><%= @employee.employeeid %></td>
    <td><b>Employee Name</b></td>
    <td><%= @employee.personnel.display_full_name %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Department</b></td>
    <td><%=  @employee.department ? @employee.department.name : "" %></td>
    <td><b>Designation</b></td>
    <td><%= @employee.designation ? @employee.designation.name : "" %></td>
    <td><b>Location</b></td>
    <td><%= @employee.location.name%></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</br>
<fieldset>
  <table cellspacing="5">
    <%= form_for :overtime_definition, :builder => LabelFormBuilder do |od| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="half_day_extra_duty_hours">
            Half Day Extra Duty Hours
          </label>
        </td>
        <td class ="datefamily">
          <%= select_time(@overtime.half_day_extra_duty_hours, {:include_blank => true, :time_separator => ":",:prefix => "half_day_extra_duty_hours"})%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="full_day_extra_duty_hours">
            Full Day Extra Duty Hours
          </label>
        </td>
        <td class ="datefamily">
          <%= select_time(@overtime.full_day_extra_duty_hours, {:include_blank => true, :time_separator => ":",:prefix => "full_day_extra_duty_hours"})%>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <%= od.sr_check_box :is_salary_basis, {}, true, false, :label => "Is Salary Basis"%>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <%= od.sr_check_box :is_fixed_amount, {}, true, false, :label => "Is Fixed Amount"%>
        <td colspan="2" id="ov_hm" style="display: none">
          Half Day Amount
          <%= od.text_field :half_day_amount, :onkeypress => "return numbersonly(event)", :style => "width:40px" %>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" id="ov_fm" style="display: none">
          Full Day Amount
          <%= od.text_field :full_day_amount, :onkeypress => "return numbersonly(event)", :style => "width:40px" %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```

**_search_overtime_employee_list.rhtml**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" id='type'>
  <tr class="tblebluehead">
    <th>
      SI.NO
    </th>
    <th>
      Code
    </th>
    <th>
      Name
    </th>
    <th>
      Department
    </th>
    <th>
      Designation
    </th>
    <th colspan="3">
      Functions
    </th>
  </tr>
  <% count=0 %><% i=0 %>
  <% for employee in @active_profile %>
    <% if i%2==0 %>
      <tr class="tablerow1">
    <% else %>
      <tr class="tablerow2">
    <%end %><% i=i+1 %>
    <td>
      <%= count=count+1 %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= employee.employeeid %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=h employee.name %>
      <%resigned = EmployeeSeparationDetail.find(:first, :conditions => ["employee_id =? and status ='Active' and approval_status ='Approved'", employee.id])%>               
      <% if resigned %>
        <span style="color:red"> (R)</span>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=h employee.department ? employee.department.name : ""%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=h employee.designation ? employee.designation.name : "" %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%=link_to "Calculation" ,:action => "new",:id=>employee.id,:flag=>"Calculation" %>
    </td>
    <% for overtime in @overtimes %>
      <% if overtime.employee_id == employee.id%>
        <td>
          <%= link_to "Re-Calculate",:action => "edit",:id=>overtime.id,:employee_id => employee.id,:flag=>"Re-Calculate" %>
        </td>
      <% end %> 
    <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<b> <%= will_paginate @active_profile,:next_label => "&gt;&gt;" ,:prev_label => "&lt;&lt;"%></b>
```

**UPDATE**

These are the parameters of lof file when i do update action.

```
Started POST "/edms/overtime_definitions/update/249?employee_id=1353&flag=Re-Calculate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-09 15:12:45 +0530
  Processing by Edms::OvertimeDefinitionsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NT+iv9FBJy87aabbNLALf50LkKv07yOR7xFA9Oe3ijs=", "overtime_definition"=>{"employee_id"=>"1353", "is_salary_basis"=>"1", "is_fixed_amount"=>"0", "half_day_amount"=>"", "full_day_amount"=>""}, "half_day_extra_duty_hours"=>{"year"=>"2000", "month"=>"1", "day"=>"1", "hour"=>"02", "minute"=>"02"}, "full_day_extra_duty_hours"=>{"year"=>"2000", "month"=>"1", "day"=>"1", "hour"=>"04", "minute"=>"04"}, "commit"=>"Update", "employee_id"=>"1353", "flag"=>"Re-Calculate", "id"=>"249"}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Changed the hidden field in **_form.rhtml** like this

```
<%= hidden_field 'overtime_definition','employee_id',:value=>@employee.id %>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Changed the @employee instance like this

```
@employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
```

**UPDATE 3**

Changed the form_tag params in **edit.rhtml** like this

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'update',:id => @overtime.id,:employee_id => params[:employee_id],:flag=> params[:flag] %>
```

Now it is not converting `employee_id` value to `id` of `overtime_definition` after update action,but the values are not updating though.

I suspect either of the `edit form` `params` or `edit/update` actions in the controller could be causing the problem.Can't figure out what it is.

Any Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Suresh, please indent your code using two space indenting. Without the indentation, it is incredibly hard to read!

Comment: @RyanBigg Apologies! I don't know how to edit like you said.

Comment: The code inside your new action should be indented with two spaces. The code inside your edit action should be indented with two spaces... and so on.

Comment: @RyanBigg You mean two space gap in between the lines of all actions in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
def update
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:id])
```

So your two models are populated with exactly the same data?

---

You'll probably be better with:

```
def update
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    @overtime = OvertimeDefinition.find(params[:employee_id])
```

If you post the params hash you get in your logs, I'll be in a better position to help, but this is the core of your problem, using `Graeme McLean`'s info too

Comment: Apologies!Can you tell me how can i view my log?

Comment: No need to apologise! The log is located in `log/[[environment]].log`. If you click onto `development.log`, you'll be able to see the requests in chronological order; allowing you to show us the params hash :)

Comment: And also see my previous question which is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22912544/cant-get-the-edit-function-working?lq=1 you might get some information on params.

Comment: Updated my question with parameters.

Comment: Updated further more to give you a clear idea.Please have a look at it.